# Bootstrap-slider disappears after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

When I refresh the page using an Ajax call, my bootstrap-slider disappears (it works fine on the initial page load).

This seems to be a similar question posed previously but I cannot get my code to work based on the answers provided related to calling a function after the ajax success and/or binding the element.  My HTML:

```
<input id="ex2" data-slider-id='ex2Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="8" data-slider-tooltip="show"/>
<h5><b><div id="gift_age"></div></b></h5>
```

Slider and ajax trigger:

```
$('#ex1').bootstrapSlider({
  formatter: function(value) {
  document.getElementById("my_age").innerHTML = value+' years old';
  return 'Age: ' + value;
  }
});

$(document).on('click','#radioBtn a', function(){
    var sel = $(this).data('title');
    reload_page(sel);
});
```

Ajax:

```
function reload_page(selected)  {
   $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/",
          data: {giftPerson:selected} ,
          success: function(data) {
                $('#mastercontainer').html(data);
          }
    });
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this, I'm not sure that this is the "solution" to the question posed, but is effective in binding outside of jquery:

```
<input id="ex1" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="70" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="8" data-slider-tooltip="show"/>
<span id="ex1SliderValLabel"><span id="ex1Age">who is 8 years old</span></span>

var slider = new Slider('#ex1');
slider.on("slide", function(value) {
$("#ex1Age").text('who is ' + value + ' years old');
});
```

Full credit to http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/